# Sticky Navigation bar not acting fully responsive when clicked on hamburger icon

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation, uinavigationbar

I have achieved to make my web page's navigation bar to be sticky and half responsive i.e. it gets shorter when resized but when shortened the click on the hamburger icon opens the menu(navbar options) on the top of the screen where it was defined initially, instead of where to screen was scrolled.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
<a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
<a href="#career">Careers</a>
<a href="#fellowship">Fellowship 2018</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon">
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
</a>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
.topnav.responsive{position: relative;}
.topnav.responsive .icon{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.topnav.responsive a{
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}
}
```

JavaScript Code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){

window.addEventListener('scroll', myFunctionForSticky);
var navbar = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunctionForSticky() {

    if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
        navbar.classList.add("sticky");
    } else {
        navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
    }
}

  var icon = document.querySelector("a.icon");
  icon.addEventListener("click",function(){
    navbar.classList.toggle("responsive");
  })

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer this, you have to first understand the concept of '**POSITIONING**' in CSS.

**TLDR;** if you really want your header to be sticky throughout the page, you have to play around with **position: fixed**

for reference you can have a look at this [pen](https://codepen.io/joshuajcollinsworth/pen/NqqaXB)

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
    .topnav.responsive{position: fixed;}
    .topnav.responsive .icon{
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
    .topnav.responsive a{
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }
}
```

this might just work, you may also have to give a z-index to your menu-icon in case it overlaps with the list-items.

Comment: Hey, it kind of worked, when I load the page and click on the hamburger icon, whole navigation bar shifts to the left, but if I scroll and click it works just fine. Also if I have clicked on the icon when scrolled and go back to the top and click on the icon then also it's working fine. What's wrong am I doing?

Comment: It is somehow depending on the scroll, if I scroll it even a little bit, it works fine. It isn't working on initial scroll position.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange, it might be caused because we haven't given top & right to the fixed container, or might be some width issue. Is it possible for you to share a Codepen link or JSfiddle link, that way I'll be able to help you better.

Comment: Hey, I see you are adding and removing a class based on the `pageYOffset` on scroll, this might be the code interfering with the header positioning.